How to use custom function in onChange event handler in React-Hook-Form?
I want to create a form with two MUI Select components. Conference and division are inter-related. Their relationships are described below.

There is a conference corresponding to each division, as shown in the teams array. When a division is selected, the corresponding conference will be automatically selected.

There are 3 divisions in each conference. When a conference is selected, the divisions list will be filtered to include divisions corresponding to that conference, e.g. if Western is selected, the divisions list only includes NorthWest, Pacific and SouthWest.


const teams = [
    {
        "conference": "Eastern",
        "division": "Atlantic"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Eastern",
        "division": "Central"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Eastern",
        "division": "Southeast"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Western",
        "division": "Northwest"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Western",
        "division": "Pacific"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Western",
        "division": "Southwest"
    }
]

export default function Demo() {
    const [divisions, setDivisions] = useState([...new Set(teams.map(obj => obj.division))]);

    const { control, formState: {errors} } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            conference: "",
            division: ""
        }
    })

    const conference = useWatch({
        control,
        name: "conference"
    })

    const division = useWatch({
        control,
        name: "division"
    })

    const handleConferenceChange = division => teams.find(obj => obj.division === division)?.conference

    const handleDivisionChange = conference => teams.filter(obj => obj.conference === conference).map(item => item.division)

    return (
        <form>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid xs={6}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth required error={!!errors.conference}>
                        <InputLabel shrink sx={{".MuiInputLabel-asterisk": {color: "error.main"}}}>Conference</InputLabel>
                        <Controller
                            name="conference"
                            control={control}
                            rules={{required: "This field is required."}}
                            render={({ field}) => (
                                <Select
                                    {...field}
                                    displayEmpty
                                    label="Conference"
                                    renderValue={value => value ? value : <InputLabel>-- Select --</InputLabel>}
                                >
                                    {[...new Set(teams.map(obj => obj.conference))].map((conference, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={conference}>{conference}</MenuItem>)}
                                </Select>
                            )}
                        />
                        {errors.conference && <FormHelperText>{errors.conference?.message}</FormHelperText>}
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid xs={6}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth required error={!!errors.division}>
                        <InputLabel shrink sx={{".MuiInputLabel-asterisk": {color: "error.main"}}}>Conference</InputLabel>
                        <Controller
                            name="division"
                            control={control}
                            rules={{required: "This field is required."}}
                            render={({ field}) => (
                                <Select
                                    {...field}
                                    displayEmpty
                                    label="division"
                                    renderValue={value => value ? value : <InputLabel>-- Select --</InputLabel>}
                                >
                                    {divisions.map((division, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={division}>{division}</MenuItem>)}
                                </Select>
                            )}
                        />
                        {errors.division && <FormHelperText>{errors.division?.message}</FormHelperText>}
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>                
            </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}

Normally react-hook-form will handle the onChange event handler of the Select component so that there is no need to specify the onChange props. However, in my case since conference and division are inter-related, how can I use the handleConferenceChange function in the Select component of conference and use the handleDivisionChange function in the Select component of division? I've studied the react-hook-form documentation and searched some tutorials on YouTube. None of them cover my use case. Could someone please teach me how my use case can be implemented using react-hook-form?
